# 400 Bad Request Flask

Tags: python, flask

First of all, I've searched this error, tried everything those guys said but it won't work for me.

So, basically, I'm having a login form, and I can't even access the page as it gives me the 400 Bad Request error.

My flask code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    users = mongo.db.users
    login_user = users.find_one({'name' : request.form['username']})

    if login_user:
        if bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['pass'].encode('utf-8'), login_user['password'].encode('utf-8')) == login_user['password'].encode('utf-8'):
            session['username'] = request.form['username']
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return 'Invalid username/password combination'
```

My HTML form:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <form method=POST action="{{ url_for('login') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log In</button>
        </form>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a similar register page but that works fine, it adds the user to the DB.

Comment: "*Everything those guys said*" Who are 'those guys', what did they say and what exactly didn't work about their proposed solutions (still receive 400 error, or something else?)? Providing these details will help people here ascertain what you have or haven't tried yet.

Comment: Put `print(request.form)` at the beginning of `login` and check if `username` and `pass` are in it. If not, try deleting `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Comment: Try with `app.config['DEBUG'] = True` to get more detailed stacktrace of error

Comment: Already had debug on, doesn't show anything besides the error itself. When I try to do what @Lee said, terminal shows me this: RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.

Comment: fix your code indents.

Comment: It wasn't like that in my editor, so that ain't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it. I had to include `if request.method == 'POST'` under the login index. No idea how I didn't come to this earlier, it makes sense that I was requesting something from the form when I didn't even had the chance to type.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your html form should be render by `login` view because in your login view you are trying to get form value:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    ...
    return render_template('your_htmlform.html')
```

And now in your form action you can add `action={{url_for('index')}}` if form submitted.